# Keras training.py error report (uninitialized 'log' object)

Tags: keras

[![Am using pyimage search pre-configured Mask R-Cnn colab ipynb with my own data.  Problem: Keras  / training.py is reporting this error:
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
854               logs = tmp_logs  # No error, now safe to assign to logs.
855               callbacks.on_train_batch_end(step, logs)
--> 856         epoch_logs = copy.copy(logs)
857
858         # Run validation.

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'logs' referenced before assignment

Any ideas as to where to address this?
][1]][1]

Comment: Which version of Keras are you using? It is likely to be an old one.

Comment: 2.3.0-tf  Should it be  upgraded to 2.7??

Comment: It is worth a short, this strange error used to happen with much older keras versions.